# Javascript regex return text between whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string such as this:

```
snippet = "Paragraph: <p>The night sky is beautiful!</p> ";
```

How do I return only the text between the first and last whitespace?
Thus returning only the paragraph tag:

```
<p>The night sky is beautiful!</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this expression:

```
snippet.match(/\s(.*)\s/)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Qhe8J/1/